# Equivalent of CTRL+W in XCODE

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio

In android studio when you press CTRL + W you can select gradualy part of code. It starts for example from one word selected, then select all content of brackets, then select whole line, then select whole content of methods and so on. Do you know is there any equivalent of this trick in XCODE?